# Jasper produces report with only one page

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I tried to fill a report with Java.

My main report has some subreports with different levels.

When I try to show my report, I see only the first page, I don't know where I'm wrong:

Follow structure and Java code:

**Report structure**

Main report: rpt_accesso_storico.jrml
First level subreport: rpt_accesso_storico_sub.jrxml
Second level subreports (called by rpt_accesso_storico_sub.jrxml)

- rpt_generale_sub.jrxml
- rpt_sociale_sub.jrxml
- rpt_ginecologico_sub.jrxml
- rpt_ostetrico_sub.jrxml
- rpt_generale_sub.jrxml
  Third level subreports: rpt_primocontatto_sub.jrxml (used in every second level report)

**The Java code**

*Step 1:*

In parameter hashmap I add all compiled subreports so in the .jrxml file I've added all subreports as Parameters as follow:

```
InputStream myIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(outByteArrayStream.toByteArray());
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(myIS);
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
if (entryName.equals("rpt_generale_sub.jrxml")) {
    parameters.put("subreportGen", jr);
} else if (entryName.equals("rpt_ostetrico_sub.jrxml")) {
    parameters.put("subreportOst", jr);
} else if (entryName.equals("rpt_infermieristico_sub.jrxml")) {
    parameters.put("subreportInf", jr);
} else if (entryName.equals("rpt_sociale_sub.jrxml")) {
    parameters.put("subreportSoc", jr);
} else if (entryName.equals("rpt_ginecologico_sub.jrxml")) {
    parameters.put("subreportGin", jr);
} else if (entryName.equals("rpt_psicologico_sub.jrxml")) {
    parameters.put("subreportPsi", jr);
} else if (entryName.equals("rpt_accesso_storico_sub.jrxml")) {
    parameters.put("subreportA", jr);   
} else if (entryName.equals("rpt_gen_primocontatto_sub.jrxml")) {
    parameters.put("subGenPrimoContatto", jr);
}
```

Obviously that snippet is inside a for loop

*Step 2:*

I have a JasperDesign object as follow where inputStream is the main report file:

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);
```

Then I compile the jasperDesign in JasperReport object and finally I try to fill report with parameters where in that object I've all compiled subreports and the list of object to fill them.

But when I see the final result I've this:

[image: Produced report]

My report has only one page, and the other informations are cut.

After that, I add the parameters:

```
Map<String, Object> myParameters = getJasperParameterMapsForAccessoStorico(lstDatiRichiesta, listPrintData, idUtente, idEnteUtente, hmListeValori);
```

**In the pom I've used jasperreports 6.20.0**

JRXML snippet code about subreport

**In the main report:**

```
<subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="20" y="6" width="550" height="40" uuid="d114b45a-18f1-41c2-96f6-92b4c507ebd5"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subreportGen">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportGen}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="subreportSoc">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportSoc}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="subreportInf">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportInf}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="subreportGin">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportGin}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="subreportOst">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportOst}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="subreportPsi">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportPsi}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="subGenPrimoContatto">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subGenPrimoContatto}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{listaEventi})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportA}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

**In the first level subreport:**

```
<groupHeader>
        <band height="55">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{idEventoClinico}=="EV_CLI_GEN"]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="0d05dbc4-3928-4d79-b633-e679eb7e9ea3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Generale]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="20" width="490" height="21" uuid="77df01e2-1477-4352-92ae-57c7a3ef56d1"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subGenPrimoContatto">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subGenPrimoContatto}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{lstRichieste})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportGen}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="50">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{idEventoClinico}=="EV_CLI_SOC"]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="be5d447e-7098-4073-9aca-6b7f8b368543"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sociale]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="10" y="20" width="490" height="21" uuid="d4f897e4-a38f-483d-aa56-de83baec648a"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subGenPrimoContatto">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subGenPrimoContatto}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{lstRichieste})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportSoc}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="50">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{idEventoClinico}=="EV_CLI_INF"]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="66cca17d-f41a-4a53-9cdc-d1f47563ec70"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Infermieristico]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="20" width="490" height="21" uuid="fed4f140-3f7c-49f0-8aca-9228559db184"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subGenPrimoContatto">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subGenPrimoContatto}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{lstRichieste})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportInf}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="50">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{idEventoClinico}=="EV_CLI_OST"]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="90dee808-1605-42d8-bce3-aa0afaf8d4b5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ostetrico]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="20" width="490" height="21" uuid="0fac5612-6938-477d-8f9b-c879349b7008"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subGenPrimoContatto">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subGenPrimoContatto}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{lstRichieste})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportOst}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="50">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{idEventoClinico}=="EV_CLI_GIN"]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="df1c0abb-b7b6-4e5b-8525-83d5455f4fde"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ginecologico]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="20" width="490" height="21" uuid="d0118f35-1fbf-4a61-9a9b-90bc9c0c8821"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subGenPrimoContatto">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subGenPrimoContatto}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{lstRichieste})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportGin}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="50">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{idEventoClinico}=="EV_CLI_PSI"]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="8a3a7a2f-8920-471f-97c3-4884a2429ff4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Psicologico]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="20" width="490" height="21" uuid="811c8cc4-8492-4b26-9680-27bff1b97abe"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subGenPrimoContatto">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subGenPrimoContatto}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{lstRichieste})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportPsi}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
</groupHeader>
```

**FINAL EDIT**

I've found an error in other custom method about post process of PDF file, so Jasper Studio and Jasper library are ok.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem is not in your java itself, but in your jrxml, could you post how your code is there?

I have a very similar example, see how I did it ->

```
public static Object printJasper(@NonNull final Collection data,
                                 @NonNull String titulo,
                                 String subReport) throws JRException {


    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("SUBREPORT_DIR",  new ClassPathResource(String.format("/target/classes/jasper/%s.jasper", subReport)));

    JasperPrint print  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(String.valueOf(new ClassPathResource(String.format("/target/classes/jasper/%s.jasper"
            , titulo))),map, buildDatasource(data));

    return exportPdf(print);

}
```

My exportPdf

```
private static byte[] exportPdf(final JasperPrint print) throws JRException {
    final var exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    final var output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(output));
    exporter.exportReport();
    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

My JRXML

```
<subreport>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="0" width="553" height="20" uuid="dcb4de43-b64f-4e50-a4b1-5ad31a1cd9a2"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("carga.ordens")]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Comment: Hi dear, I think is not a problem of .jrxml. I update my question with jrxml snippet

Comment: Note that the main expects multiple parameters, but in <subreportExpression> it only expects $P{subreportA}.

Do a test and pass just one parameter to see if it will list the sub.

You must do your parameters and subs logic inside java, the jrxml will only get the correct sub via <subreportExpression>